# Sample code to open the Calendar from the iPad device

Tags: ios, calendar, xcode4.5

I am new to iOS programming.My requirement is to open the Calendar from the device to add event in the calendar.Can you tell me How to proceed?

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the Event Kit. It allows working with calendar http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: The Link is broken, However thanks for reference to EventKit